# Resetting screens to default react-native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using this library with bottom tabs:
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation

for navigation, I have 3 tabs at the bottom, one of them is for home, the thing is  I move from home screen to another screen it gets added to the stack, I want to be able to reset the stack whenever I click to the home icon again at bottom tabs.

The `route.js`  is sth like this for the home icon at bottomTab:

```
stack: {
  children: [
    {
      component: {
        name: home,
      }
    },
  ],
  options: {
    bottomTab: {
      iconInsets: {top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0},
      titleDisplayMode: 'alwaysHide',
      icon: require('../assets/images/home.png'),
      selectedIconColor: colors.primary,
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add listener if user click the bottom tab . With help of [registerbottomtabselectedlistener](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events?id=registerbottomtabselectedlistener) you can achieve this . You can use [popToRoot](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api?id=poptorootcomponentid-mergeoptions) to send user to root of stack

```
// Subscribe
const bottomTabEventListener = Navigation.events().registerBottomTabSelectedListener(({ selectedTabIndex, unselectedTabIndex }) => {
   Navigation.popTo(componentId);  // check selectedTabIndex and send to home
});
...
// Unsubscribe
bottomTabEventListener.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from the snippet you posted but I think you are trying to get bottom tabs to work.  This is incomplete but hopefully this gets you on track.

```
const AppTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  App: AppStack, // stack navigator
  Contacts: ContactsStack, // stack navigator
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen, // single component import
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
          size={26}
          name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-settings' : 'settings'}
          style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
          color={focused ? "red" : "gray"}
        />
      ),
    }
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'App',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'green',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    tabStyle: { marginBottom: -10 }
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  App: AppTabs,
  Auth: AuthStack,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
}));
```